# What is with the reccommendation to use `www` domain on GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, cname

If you look at the documentation for GitHub pages, it has a pretty strong reccommendation to use a `www` domain for your custom domain site hosted on GitHub Pages.

From here: https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-supported-custom-domains#www-subdomains

> A www subdomain is the most commonly used type of subdomain, in which
>   the www stands for World Wide Web. For example, www.example.com is a
>   www subdomain because it contains the subdomain part www.
>
> We strongly recommend that you use a www subdomain for these reasons:
>
> - It gives your GitHub Pages site the benefit of our Content Delivery Network.
> - It is more stable because it is not affected by changes to the IP addresses of GitHub's servers.
> - Pages will load significantly faster because Denial of Service attack protection can be implemented more efficiently.

Does this mean if I do not use a `www` domain I will not get the benefits of a CDN or DDOS Attack Protection?

What is the technical reason why there is a difference between a `www` and non-`www` domain here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference lies in how you point the site to GitHub's servers in DNS.

The simplest use of DNS is to point a domain name, at whatever level, at an IP address, using an A record. The same address will be used by all users, and can be changed only by the owner of the "zone" where the A record was added - in this case you, configuring the zone of your custom domain.

A smarter way is to *alias* a particular domain name to a different zone - in this case one managed by GitHub - using a CNAME record. The owners of that zone can then change the IP address as needed, and can even give different answers to different users based on their location (which is where the CDN reference comes from).

The key restriction however is that *you can't use a CNANE as the root of a zone*. See [this Server Fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/613829/why-cant-a-cname-record-be-used-at-the-apex-aka-root-of-a-domain) for the technical details.

If you own "example.com", you can point an A record for the root of that domain at one GitHub IP address (or a few, selected essentially at random by visitors), but will give GitHub more freedom to route the traffic if you point a CNAME for a sub-domain, like "www.example.com".

Some DNS providers offer tools to work around this limitation by adding a fake record for the root of the domain that looks like a CNAME, but may be labelled differently (e.g. ANAME, ALIAS). When asked for the root A record, the DNS provider looks up the actual A records for that domain and returns those. This is useful for records which change over time, but because the address is being looked up by your DNS provider not the actual visitor, it may still prevent GitHub serving the best address for that visitor.

Comment: Learn something new every day. Thank you.

Comment: An interesting point is that if you already use Cloudflare for DNS then the restriction that a CNAME can't be at the root doesn't apply: https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cname-flattening-rfc-compliant-cnames-at-a-domains-root/ - I don't know how many other major DNS providers offer a similar feature, but it's nice to know if you really don't want that `www`.

Comment: @TravisBritz The restriction still exists; what DNS providers do is provide convenient user interfaces for setting your A records based on some other domain. In CloudFlare's case, they show it in their UI as a CNAME record, but promise not to ever return it as such; other providers have other names for it, like ANAME, but do essentially the same thing. I'll update the answer to cover this possibility though.

Comment: @IMSoP correct, and that point is covered in the linked blog article as well. My wording may have been confusing - the restriction exists from a protocol standpoint, but in a practical sense the users of such services don't need to be concerned with the protocol restriction, and therefore wouldn't require the `www`. Services that *don't* allow root CNAME flattening (as CloudFlare called it) will prevent CNAME record types at root domains from their UI, and services that *do* offer the feature should simply allow the option and perform the additional steps transparently to the user.

Comment: @TravisBritz As pointed out by the other answer on this page (and now by mine as well), there is still a downside to using these features: because the DNS provider is effectively proxying the DNS response, GitHub can no longer see where the real request is coming from. That's why most providers label this as a special pseudo-record type rather than pretending it's a CNAME, because it is not completely transparent or equivalent to a real CNAME.

Comment: @IMSoP wouldn't that depend on the specific provider and implementation? For example, if the proxied DNS request is itself coming from an edge server which is located near the user making the request, wouldn't the returned geo-specific IP still (mostly) be for servers in the same region as the user? Also, if your DNS provider were itself a caching proxy (as CloudFlare can be configured to do for free) then it may ultimately still not matter, as the IP returned would be for one of their own servers near the user, layered on top of whatever CDN/DoS protection GitHub is providing.

Comment: @TravisBritz I think at that point you're into "there's exceptions to every rule" territory. There's absolutely scenarios where you can understand the underlying systems enough to go ahead and point your domain apex, but it needs a lot more than just "CNAME flattening" or "apex aliases" or whatever other jargon providers come up with. Most people reading the guidance that led to this question are using GitHub pages because they _don't_ have that expertise, and so that they _don't_ need to worry about layering a caching proxy in front of their content, and for them it is good advice.

Answer (score 2):

DNS does not provide a reliable mechanism for forwarding on apex/root records (e.g. `example.com`) but does for subdomains (CNAME). In practice this means that while you can point an `A` record to a single IP address corresponding to a node on Github's infrastructure, they aren't able to route DNS lookups for your apex record to other IP addresses that are closer to the request (CDN) or use DNS to mitigate the effects of a (D)DoS attack.

Some DNS providers do offer synthetic records (ALIAS, ANAME) that mimic the behavior of a CNAME record with apex domains (e.g. [dnsimple](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/alias-record/)), but they're not widely available, introduce additional complexity and latency, and don't provide the same level of geographic routing opportunities to Github et al.